# Using multicols and auto multiple choice, how to prevent aswers from "overflowing" into the next column?

Tags: formatting, multicol, auto-multiple-choice

Using auto multiple choice and the multicols environment, some possible answers "overflow" into the next column, which makes it hard to read the full answer quickly. I would like to prevent this behaviour, forcing possible answers to stay in a single column.

Such an example is illustrated on the screenshot below : the red text is a single answer, at the bottom of the first column, and overflows on the second column : [image]

This is how I currently define such questions and answers :

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\usepackage{fontspec}
  
\usepackage[bloc,completemulti]{automultiplechoice}
\usepackage{multicol}
  
\begin{document}
  
\AMCrandomseed{1237893}
  
\element{amc}{
  \begin{questionmult}{tag}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \begin{reponses}
        \bonne{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}
        \bonne{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore}
        \mauvaise{et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam}
        \mauvaise{quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat}
      \end{reponses}
    \end{multicols}
  \end{questionmult}
}
  
\exemplaire{1}{
    \melangegroupe{amc}
    \restituegroupe{amc}     
}
  
\end{document}
```

How can I change the behaviour of multicols, possibly auto multiple choice, to prevent answers from overflowing ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: As you wish, there is not much to add.

Comment: Cannot find automultiplechoice package.  However, the easy solution is to add `\columnbreak` where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of a random `automultiplechoice.dtx` I found online, it seems there is `\AMCBoxedAnswers` which you can add in your preamble to ensure all answers are put inside `minipage`s.
For future questions, please make sure you give all the information necessary so that we can compile the code on our side…